# Regex for first n matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like below

```
const str = '_ _  _ _  _ _ _ _'
```

How can i replace first 2 `_` ?

For example i need replace two `_`

```
const newString = '     _ _  _ _ _ _'?
```

I am trying with string.replace and Regexp.

How can i find the first n specific symbols using regex?
For example i need to find `3` in below string:

```
^[_]{3}
```

But not it matches only 3 `_` in a row like `___`

Comment: Your question is a little hard to follow, but is this what you're looking for? `^(?:_\s?){3}`

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs could try to explain what your solution would match, in case he (or me or someone else) isn't profficient in regex. ;)

Comment: Sure. Would match exactly 3 underscores`_` & `{3}`, with or without a proceeding space `\s?`, as long as the string is at the start of the string `^`. It's within a non-capturing group since we are grouping the underscore and optional whitespace character.

Comment: A general case involves a callback method with a counter. Or, if there are always 2 `_` there , just use capturing groups/backreferences.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs ^(?:_\s?){3}. Matches '_ _ _ ', but not matches three _ when '_ _(doublespace)_ _ '

Comment: You can just replace the `\s?` with `\s*`

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but you could simply run a non-global replace twice. Or run a `for` loop over the number of times required.

```js
var str = '_ _  _ _  _ _ _ _';
str = str.replace('_',' ').replace('_',' ');
console.log(str);
```